# Specific user display name by id with shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, shortcode

I have been trying several combinations for displaying the display name for a specific user by ID in WordPress, but in the end, I couldn't make it work. I need help, please. The code I'm trying to use is the following:

```
function custom_id_display_name($atts, $content = null) {

   extract( shortcode_atts( 
           array('id' => '0',), $atts 
                          ) 
           );

 /*  return $display_name( $user_id, 96 ); // display the specific user_id's name*/
   return get_display_name($atts['id'], 96);
}

add_shortcode('custom_display_name','custom_id_display_name');
```

The "funny" thing is that the code worked well for custom avatar with a different return,

```
 return get_avatar($atts['id'], 96);
```

so I have no idea why it's not working for the display name. Thanks for your help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_user_by( string $field, int|string $value )` [get_user_by](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/) here is the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627805/get-user-byid-not-returning-anything-not-even-an-error) referance

Answer (score 0):

First you get the user object.

```
$user = get_user_by( 'ID', $user_id );
```

Then display name you get with:

```
$display_name = $user->display_name;
```